# display multiple R Embedded Graph in multiple panel winform c#

Tags: c#, r, winforms

I want to show multiple graphs from R that embedded in winform c# using R.NET. I have two forms. Form 1 consist of multiple panels and form 2 consist of some parameters based on user input. My scenario, after user input the parameter then graph will show in panels at form 1 not in popup window.
I have tried some code that I got from https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7 or https://peterdaidinh.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/displaying-an-r-graph-within-a-c-net-winform/ they're good in showing graph embedded in the form but only in one panel so multiple graphs will show only in one panel.My question is how to show multiple embedded graphs in multiple panels.
Here is my code at form2:

```
    namespace RNETGraph

{public partial class RGraphForm : Form
{
    private readonly RGraphAppHook cbt;
    REngine engine;

    public RGraphForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        engine = REngine.GetInstance();

    }

    private void btnShowGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel pan2 = data.getPanel2();
        RGraphAppHook cbt1 = new RGraphAppHook { GraphControl = pan2 };
        cbt1.Install();
        engine.Evaluate(&quot;plot(rnorm(100))&quot;);
        cbt1.Uninstall();

        Panel pan1 = data.getPanel1();
        RGraphAppHook cbt = new RGraphAppHook { GraphControl = pan1 };
        cbt.Install();
        engine.Evaluate(&quot;plot(rnorm(500))&quot;);
        cbt.Uninstall();
    }     
}}
```

Comment: I am the author of the hook-solution you mentioned above. The method works, but memory management is an issue and closing down cleanly is brittle. So, keep it simple, don't use two hooks, double problems. Better, assemble the graph in R, e.g. by using facets or with split() for standard graphics.

Comment: So I should only use one hook then add some method for standard graphics, right? Have the memory management problem got the solution yet?

Comment: Memory management: I have one application that is often started, and restarted, but the computer is always on. This still leads - not on every start - to an accumulation of Rscript in the task manager; check it out. So the computer has to be restarted once  a week to get rid of the hanging scripts.

Comment: Any pointer to how to fix the memory management problem? Application.Exit(); in FormClosing appears to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new graphics window using `win.graph()` or `dev.new()`:

```
cbt.Install();
engine.Evaluate("win.graph()");    
engine.Evaluate(&quot;plot(rnorm(500))&quot;);
cbt.Uninstall();
```

Comment: please try to explain what this answer does, rather than just post code

Comment: win.graph() or dev.new() opens a r graphics window.

Comment: Sorry - to be more clear - this explanation should be in the answer so it's easy for others to see and understand, e.g., above. You can edit your own answers any time - please do if this isn't quite right