# How to embed a R plot in a Winform in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, r, winforms, r.net

I am using R.NET to perform computation in my C# application and
now I'd like to display the results in a Winform.

Anyone could advise on how to embed a R plot in a winform using R.NET ?

I found the below post which seems outdated as I can't find any reference nor Nuget package for the RNETGraph namespace that they use. The link referenced in the post have also been archived.

[display multiple R Embedded Graph in multiple panel winform c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857789/display-multiple-r-embedded-graph-in-multiple-panel-winform-c-sharp)

And I would like to avoid the ugly solution of saving the image and then loading it in a PictureBox as I need to change the plot dynamically according to user input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dieter Menne's [RGraphHooks](https://github.com/sagreine/mylife/blob/master/RGraphHook.cs) to display R's plot output in a graphical WinForms element (e.g. a Windows.Forms.Panel). RGraphHooks has a dependency to [Dino Esposito's Win32 hooks library](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script.npp/blob/master/src/CSScriptNpp/Interop/LocalWindowsHook.cs).

Usage of RGraphHooks is quite simple. See [this blog post](https://peterdaidinh.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/displaying-an-r-graph-within-a-c-net-winform/) by Peter Dai Dinh for a small demo program.

What you basically do is, you attach an RGrapHook to a specific control in your WinForms GUI and then wrap your `engine.Evaluate("plot(...)")` in this hook:

```
RGraphAppHook cbt = new RGraphAppHook { GraphControl = panelForPlot };

cbt.Install();
engine.Evaluate("plot(rnorm(100))");
cbt.Uninstall();
```

Comment: Is there a header that needs to added to be able to use RGraphAppHook?

Comment: It has been a while that I played around with RGraphHook and I actually have no project that uses this library anymore. As far as I remember, you only had to add both RGraphHooks.cs and the Win32 Hooks .cs file to your project.

Comment: Thanks. I found the RGraphHooks.cs and the WindowsHook.dll files.

Answer (score 0):

I never got hold of R.NET - documentation just wasn't very clear.

There is another option, however. You can use the command line to transfer arguments from your C# application to your R.Script.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "Rscript.exe [directory here]\\script.R 10 arg2"; //what comes after script.R are the arguments you are passing. 
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, it is very easy to retrieve the arguments in the R Script. Just use:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

var1 <- args[1]  #Argument 1
var2 <- args[2]  #Argument 2
```

Addendum: Please note, you should have your RScript.exe in the environment variables in order to get the above to work.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't answer the question at all... and there are much easier ways with R.NET to pass arguments to the Rengine...